# JavaFX maven multi module application packaging

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I want to package a multimodule JavaFX application using "JavaFX Maven Plugin"
the application is structured like so:
multimodule-application
    - client
    - server 
    - core

Creating an exe file from each module works fine.

```
[Files]
Source: "gcommerce\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;
Source: "gcommerce\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;
Source: "E:\IT\programmes\PostgreSQL-10.5-1-win64-bigsql.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}";  Flags: deleteafterinstall ;
```

So, my problem is how to create a bundle using files from modules:

```
client 
server 
core
```

Now, how to refer to those file in inno script file ?

```
[Files]
Source: "client\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;
Source: "server\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;
Source: "E:\IT\programmes\PostgreSQL-10.5-1-win64-bigsql.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}";  Flags: deleteafterinstall ;
```